# Key cloak from cURL lands at Login Page

Tags: curl, keycloak

So I'm implementing Keycloak, and I have it working with my ASP.Net Core MVC application using OIDC, but only when using the web browser.  What I need is to set this up to be able to use cURL to get the data.
I am able to get the authentication to work and get the token, but I can't seem to get the authorization to work, I keep ending up at the Login page for Keycloak.
All the examples, the few of them, I can see say that all that is needed is the header ***"authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}"*** and the application's URL. 
I have the client setup for the following:

Client protocol: opened-connect
Access Type: public
Standard Flow Enabled: On
Implicit Flow Enabled: Off
Direct Access Grant Enabled: On
 
Authorization Enabled: Off

Root URL: [blank]
Valid Redirect URIs: *
Base URL: [blank]
Admin URL: [blank]
Web Origins: http://keycloakserver:8080/auth

Like I said, web browser works because I can enter my reds on the login page, but I can't using cURL.  I can get the token using cURL and can see in the log the successful login/authentication event.

I have tried just about every iteration I can come up with and no joy.  Help....  I'm gonna keep poking around, hopefully not in vein...

Comment: Can you post the arguments you sent with curl?

Comment: Yeah, so I here's the whole match:

Comment: Yeah, so I here's the whole match:
<br>
RESULT=`curl -X POST http://keycloakserver:8080/auth/realms/Lab/protocol/openid-connect/token -d 'username=me' -d 'password=pass' -d 'grant_type=password' -d 'client_id=myClient' -d 'client_secret=myKey'`
<br>
TOKEN=`echo RESULT | sed 's/.*access_token":"//g' | sed 's/".*//g'`
<br>
curl -L --request GET --url "http://myapplication:5000/api/endpoint" -H "authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
<br>
I have been able to verify using REST clients that the value being pulled into $TOKEN is accurate, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Which OIDC library are you using on the .Net side ?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect v1.1.2.
I'm going to post my middleware setup below, I have to split it up though

Comment: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
CookieHttpOnly = true,
CookieSecure = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
})

Comment: app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions() {
AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
Authority = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ServerAddress"] + "/auth/realms/" + Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:Realm"],
RequireHttpsMetadata = false, //only in development
PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ClientId"],

Comment: ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ClientSecret"],
ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
SaveTokens = true,
AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet
})

Comment: Just wondering if anyone had any additional advice?

Comment: Circling back to this today hasn’t given any further results. Scouring the net doesn’t give me any good insights into this particular issue.